# Code-First Many to Many table not using provided id columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm using EF6.2.0.

I need to create a many-many relationship between two POCO classes, but I need to add a custom property against the link.
So, I created this class to serve as my many-many link POCO:

```
class SampleGroupSpecies
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SpeciesId { get; set; }
    public bool IsContaminated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Species Species { get; set; }
}
```

however, when EF generates the table, I get this:

```
dbo.SampleGroupSpecies
   Columns
      GroupId (PK, FK, int, not null)
      SpeciesId (PK, int, not null)
      IsContaminated (bit, not null)
      Species_Id (FK, int, not null)
```

As you can see, it's creating its own "Species_Id" column and using that as the foreign key, but that's not what I want.

I can *obviously* add a `GroupSpeciesId` column, set that as the only `[key]` and it'll all work as if by magic, but that's not good design.

I'm trying to avoid using fluent and just use annotations if possible.

Someone tell me where I've gone wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by me setting the navigation property incorrectly on the Species POCO - It was not set as a collection of SampleGroupSpecies, but as a single - meaning EF was correctly trying to create a one-many relationship, but I was trying to force it to create a many-to-many when it couldn't :)

Solution was to check both related POCOs to make sure their navigation properties are set as a collection, rather than a single instance.